# PBS bash script

Tags: bash, pbs, qsub

I need to sent the name of PBS job name as the last folder in the working directory. I apply the following line:

```
#PBS -N (eval "${PWD##*/}")
```

But seems it is an incorrect option.

Answer (score 0):

does this not work:

```
PBS -N "${PWD##*/}"
```